# Spring boot restful web service. Xml response wrongly formatted

Tags: java, rest, maven, spring-boot

I've got a simple Restful webService using Spring Boot 2.1, Java 8, running on Eclipse Neon. Im sending the following request:

```
<patentListWrapper>
    <patentList>
        <patent>
            <guid>bbb</guid>
        </patent>
       <patent>
           <guid>ccc</guid>
       </patent>
    </patentList>
</patentListWrapper>
```

and im getting back the following (incorrect) response:

```
<patentListWrapper>
    <patentList>
        <patentList>
            <guid>ddd</guid>
        </patentList>
       <patentList>
           <guid>eee</guid>
       </patentList>
    </patentList>
</patentListWrapper>
```

ie i've got 2 patentList elements in the response ,instead of an inner patent element, and I don't know why. My 2 POJO classes to map the request are:

```
public class PatentListWrapper {

private List<Patent> patents;

public List<Patent> getPatentList() {
    return patents;
}

public void setPatentList(List<Patent> patents) {
    this.patents = patents;
}   
}
```

and:

```
public class Patent {

private String guid;

public String getGuid() {
    return guid;
}

public void setGuid(String guid) {
    this.guid = guid;
}

public Patent() {
    super();
}
}
```

my REST Controller class is:

```
@RestController
public class PndController {
@Autowired
ReadFromDb db;

@RequestMapping(value = "/guidRequest/xmlList", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { "application/xml", "text/xml" }, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE )

public PatentListWrapper guidSearchList(@RequestBody  PatentListWrapper patentListWrapper) {
    System.out.println("DS in  guidSearchList()");

    patentListWrapper = db.readGuidsFromDb(patentListWrapper); // Set the guid in the patents List in patentListWrapper

    return patentListWrapper;
}
}
```

and ReadFromDb class:

```
@Repository
public class ReadFromDb {

public PatentListWrapper readGuidsFromDb(PatentListWrapper patentListWrapper) {
    List<Patent> patents=  patentListWrapper.getPatentList();
    for(Patent patent : patents) {
        patent.setGuid("aaa");
    }
    patentListWrapper.setPatentList(patents);
    return patentListWrapper;
}

}
```

I'm sending my resuest using the windows ARC Advanced Rest Client:
[Rest client](https://electronjs.org/apps/advanced-rest-client) with Content-type=application/xml

I've established that **both** patentList element names map to get**PatentList**() in PatentListWrapper. How do I get the response envelope to match the request envelop? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it is true , just create the getter setter method with the same variable name like below instead of using different names for getter setter methods

```
private List<Patent> patents;

public List<Patent> getPatents() {
 return patents;
}

public void setPatents(List<Patent> patents) {
 this.patents = patents;
}
```

or use the GSON and use @JsonProperty and define the required value name , further if you are not using the IDE to generate getters and setters you better use lombok plugin .

Comment: @Thilanka_A_Weerasinghe Thanks but if I do this I get back 2 patents elements in the response (no patentList element)

Comment: post your ReadFromDb class as well.

Comment: @Thilanka_A_Weerasinghe  the request is in xml format, not json and the getters and setters were generated by the IDE.

Comment: please paste your ReadFromDb class , yes i can see those are in xml , sorry for mentioning to use GSON

Comment: @Thilanka_A_Weerasinghe ReadFromDb  added